# getting predict_proba is not available when run my code

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I am building algorithm for not so big dataset (1000 records)

but it has around 2000 columns

I am getting this error

```
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 603, in _check_proba
    raise AttributeError("predict_proba is not available when "

AttributeError: predict_proba is not available when  probability=False
```

This is my code

```
multilabel_binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
multilabel_binarizer.fit(df['Result'])
y = multilabel_binarizer.transform(df['Result'])
    
X = df[df.columns.difference(["Result"])]

xtrain, xval, ytrain, yval = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=9)
lr = SVC(gamma='auto')
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(lr)
clf.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
y_pred = clf.predict(xval)
```

How to avoid such error

When I run the same code for LogisticRegression it works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because logistic regression by default outputs probabilities. SVM's default output is binary (-1, 1) which is given by the design of the algorithm itself (finding the best separating hyperplane and either the target is on one side or the other).

If you want SVM to output probabilities, you need to specify `probability=True` when you are instantiating the `SVC` class.

```
lr = SVC(gamma='auto', probability=True)
```

This will internally use a different mechanism to get the probabilistic output from SVM.